# Didn't find class "com.androidclass.simpleprogram.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.androidclass.simpleprogram-2.apk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-logcat

I am writing a basic application in eclipse . The MainActivity.java class is as below :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView tv; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText("Hello Billal");

    }

}
```

My Manifest file is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidclass.simpleprogram"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But when I am running this application I am getting exception . THe logcat shows below error .

```
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.androidclass.simpleprogram/com.androidclass.simpleprogram.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.androidclass.simpleprogram.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.androidclass.simpleprogram-2.apk
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.androidclass.simpleprogram.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.androidclass.simpleprogram-2.apk
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
12-04 12:50:26.466: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     ... 11 more
```

How can I solve this error ?